# Problem turning 2D array into 1D how to convert matrix of vertexes into matrix of xy values

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, multi-dimensional-scaling

I want to turn a 2D array like this `[ [x, y], [a, b], [z, e] ]` into `[x, y, a, b, z, e]`
I have tried multiple thing with indexes and for loops but most of them don't work and the one that did was very buggy and sketchy how do I do that i c++ i am a beginner, and I am trying to learn about matrices

Comment: Do you want it to work with standard arrays or maybe `std::vector<>`?

Comment: i cant use std::vector or array i am using this array with modern opengl and it only supports float[] arrays

Comment: It's not a problem as `std::vector<>` has a `.data()` method which returns `float*` array.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with my code its in modern opengl

Comment: here is the code    //creating a vertex buffer object
  VertexBuffer VBuff;
  VertexArray vertexArray;

  //creating a vertex array
  vector <float> vertices = {
   -1, 0,
   1, 0
  };

  //writing a vertex array to our vertex buffer
  VBuff.write(vertices.data(), sizeof(vertices.data()));

  shader.setColor(1,0,0,1);

  // bind buffers, ...
  VBuff.bind();

Comment: vertexArray.bind();
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

  glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeof(vertices.data()) / 4 / 2);

  // unbind buffers, ...
  VBuff.unbind();
  vertexArray.unbind();

  VBuff.~VertexBuffer();
  vertexArray.~VertexArray();

  glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  glfwPollEvents();

Comment: but even if it did work it still would not have solved the problem

Comment: Could you please provide entire code, like paste it to the pastebin.com or edit the main post, I would be easier to read that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235755/discussion-between-milosz-brzechczyn-and-farouk).

Comment: it is a very big project with many files i'll post the main.cpp file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Sv3JL174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a new array.
Use the following code which is quite simple and clear as well

```
  int arr[rows*columns];
    int a=0;
    int array[rows][columns]={assign values}; 
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
           arr[a]=array[i][j];  
           a++;
        }
    }
```